# How to convert data of any types into a workbook object in python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I got a data, which can be of any type i.e. DataFrame, dict or something else in python. How can I use python to convert it to a workbook instead of using the load_workbook in openpyxl. I know that using openpyxl.load_workboo("xx.xlsx") could get me a workbook object, but that is not what i want. e.g. I have a dateframe below

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A":[1,2,3,4,5],
    "B":[11,22,33,44,55],
    "C":[111,222,333,444,555]
})
   A   B    C
0  1  11  111
1  2  22  222
2  3  33  333
3  4  44  444
4  5  55  555
```

Instead of saving the dataframe to excel, I wonder if I could turn the dataframe directly into a workbook instead of saving it to excel, and then generate a workbook object using the load workbook method in openpyxl

Comment: Hi, have you done some searching around? Pandas has direct options to convert dataframes to excel files. For eg: `df.to_excel`

Comment: Instead of saving the dataframe to excel, I wonder if I could turn the dataframe directly into a workbook instead of saving it to excel, and then generate a workbook object using the load workbook method in openpyxl

Comment: but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt understand why you want to create a workbook object in two ways, ie by converting dataframe directly and also using load workbook method.
However, there is solution available in openpyxl's documentation to convert a dataframe into a workbook object.
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(r)
```

Comment: Thank you very much,it works,that's exactly what I want.